# O que é string ISO-8859-1?

Tags: php, string, iso-8859-1

Estou precisando usar o utf8_decode e o utf8_encode do PHP, ai vi algo sobre string ISO-8859-1. O que seria isso?

Não quero saber como usar, no momento, quero somente saber o significado de ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Não é duplicata não. Eu quero saber o que é, não como usar.

Comment: Por isso que é **possível** duplicata. Você leu toda a(s) resposta(s)?

Comment: Primeiro link do google no wikipédia tem isso

Comment: UzumakiArtanis, obrigado! O Leandro e Alexandre ja sanaram minha dúvida!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp) é o conjunto de caracteres padrão da **Maioria** dos navegadores.

> Os primeiros 128 caracteres do ISO-8859-1 é o conjunto original ASCII (números 0-9, etras maiúsculas e minúsculas do alfabeto Inglês e alguns caracteres especiais).

Basicamente A ISO 8859-1 é a decodificação dos caracteres Latinos. Veja a tabela [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_8859.asp).

Por efeito de curiosidade, a única diferença entre o utf-8 e a ISO 8859-1 é a codificação, ou seja ambos tem os mesmos caracteres porém com codificações diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

(informalmente, Latin1) é uma codificação de caracteres do alfabeto latino.
Como todos os 191 caracteres codificados pela ISO 8859-1 são gráficos (não são caracteres de controle) e são compatíveis com a maioria dos navegadores.
Segue lista dos caracteres. [Lista de caracteres](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Como se trata de uma codificação de caracteres latinos, aceita acentos e alguns caracteres especiais.